Achieving a specific throughput in kafka
I have worked on kafka (kraft) with basic event-driven architecture. Now, I was asked to setup kafka to support 5 million messages per hour throughput on 3 KB payloads.
Could anyone please point out towards any source which can be referred for this? I learnt the basics in the job and never got a chance to formally learn it.

If you have the resources, the best and most accurate estimations would come from designing a small scale POC / demo and load testing it to get the feel of resources stress. There are many configurations you can tinker with both in clients (consumers, producers) and brokers, some to consider are retention time, protocols, OS filesystem and network configs, # of partitions and concurrent clients, storage, batching messages on read and write.
Also try using kafka-producer-perf-test and kafka-consumer-perf-test to have a better feel of your assumptions and load test your demo environment (before testing with your message structure, playing with compression and considering schema validation needs).
Some resources I've found helpful when running sizing estimations for Kafka clusters:

Cloudera - Sizing estimation based on network and disk message throughput
AWS - Best practices for right-sizing your Apache Kafka clusters...
Apache Kafka Partition Calculator

I would recommend reading them all, and combining the desied formulas to google sheets / excel, then you will have a simple calculator you can play with and tune its formulas to better represent your environment and specific requirements.
